# What is the best way to manipulate algebraic expressions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I realy tryied to do it, but I didn´t get it. I don´t have the lecture on the College and sometimes I have to manipulate algebraic expressions.

Knowing that $K=Q_2/W$ and that $W=Q_1-Q_2$ and that $Q_1/Q_2=T_1/T_2$.

Here there´s my attempt. So may someone help me? What is the right way to manipulate these expressions in order to get this

[image]

Here it´s another attempt. [image]

Comment: Always wear gloves and safety goggles.

Comment: What are you solving for, or where are you trying to end up from those starting points?

Comment: I´m trying to find K in function of the T only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what you want, is it this ?
$$K=\frac{Q_2}{W}=\frac{Q_2}{Q_1-Q_2}=\frac{1}{\frac{Q_1}{Q_2}-1}=\frac{1}{\frac{T_1}{T_2}-1}=\frac{T_2}{T_1-T_2}$$

Comment: Yes. See my attempt if is correct. Thanks

Comment: It's strange, I don't think we use the same notation : For instance , I don't think you can simplify the $T_1$ in your second attempt but in the last line before the end, you are coherent with this notation in your simplification which then gives you the right result.

Comment: Sorry for my handwritten but we using the same notation despite the  I have written my attempt. In this case Am I right?

Comment: If we're using the same notation, you can't simplify $T_1$. Remember : $$\frac{a}{b} \times \frac{1}{\frac{c}{d}}=\frac{ad}{bc}$$

Comment: The second simplification is also wrong which gives you the right result : $$\frac{1}{a}\times \frac{1}{b} \neq a\times \frac{1}{b}$$